# App crashes on segue after embedding view controllers

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have a segue that works fine when it is directly from a UIViewController to a UITableViewController, but when I embed the second view in a navigation controller, the segue no longer seems to work and I get `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional` error. I don't believe I need to change the code. Should I rebuild the app somehow? I've read about errors in Xcode 6 beta (though I'm using 6.1) that cause the order in which a developer builds the app to have an effect.

Comment: Do you perform the segue from code? If so, please add some code to your question and show the exact line where it occurs. If it is a pure storyboard segue (without code), try to delete an recreate the segue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because destination of your segue is not as NavigationController. You must set the controller as NavagationController first.

Try this code

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
     if (segue.identifier == "showItemSegue") {   
          let controller: Your_TableViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController).topViewController as Your_TableViewController 
     }
}
```

I hope this work